# Rxjs - Not grabbing the value of dom element in observable

Tags: javascript, dom, reactive-programming, observable, rxjs

I am trying to make a widget that searches an array of colors from an input box.

In my search Observable in my js file I reference the input dom element where I am getting my key presses from.  Whenever I try to grab the value of $input I am getting undefined.  However, when I go into the console I am able to select the element and grab the value.  This should be updating the value so that I send throttled keypresses over to my search function.  Currently, I am sending back undefined to my searchColors function.

This throws a `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined`

I think my $input is the main bug in this code.  Thanks for the help!

Javascript

```
var Observable = Rx.Observable; 
  var colors = ["AliceBlue",...,"YellowGreen"].map(function (n) {return n.toLowerCase()});
  var $input = document.querySelector("#bg-color-input");
  var $container = document.querySelector("#bg-color-container");
  var $results = document.querySelector("div#ac-list");
  var $clear = document.querySelector("#bg-color-clear");
  var $node, change;

  function setBackground (color) {
    this.style.backgroundColor = color;
  }

  function clearColors () {
    while (this.firstChild) {
      this.removeChild(this.firstChild);
    }
  }

  function searchColors (substr) {
    colors.forEach(function (color) {
      if(color.indexOf(substr.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
        var el = document.createElement('div');
        el.innerHTML = color;
        el.style.backgroundColor = color;
        el.className = 'color-node col-md-1'
        $results.appendChild(el)
      }
    })

    $node = document.querySelectorAll(".color-node");

    change = Observable.fromEvent($node, 'click')
      .map(function (e) { return e.target.innerHTML });

    change.subscribe(setBackground.bind($container));
  }

  var search = Observable.fromEvent($input, 'keypress').
    throttle(20).
    map(function (key) { return $input.value; }).
    distinctUntilChanged().
    map(function (search) { searchColors(search); });

  var clear = Observable.fromEvent($clear, 'click').
    map(function (e) { return e })

  search.subscribe(searchColors.bind($results))
  clear.subscribe(clearColors.bind($results))
```

HTML

```
  <div class="container">
    <div id="bg-color-container">
      <h1>Change the Background Color</h1>
      <p>
        By entering a valid named CSS color you can change the background color of this div.
      </p>
      <input type="text" id="bg-color-input">
      <button id="bg-color-clear">Clear</button>
      <div class="row" id="ac-list">
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is a jsbin of my code
http://jsbin.com/ravagi/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something that can be traced down by using the `do` operator or `console.log` logging instruction to trace the execution of the operator chain. By doing this I found out that :

- you call `searchColors` twice. The second time the value passed will always be undefined because you haven-t returned a value in `map(function (search) { searchColors(search); });` so when you subscribe to that stream, you get `undefined`. Maybe you added that code after the fact for debugging purposes?
- once you correct that, you will see that `$input.value` is still `undefined`. The problem here is that you react on `keypress`. You should react on `keyup`. At `keypress` time, the input box has not yet been updated with your key.

In short, replace the appropriate line with :

```
  var search = Observable.fromEvent($input, 'keyup').
    throttle(20).
    map(function (key) { return $input.value; }).
    distinctUntilChanged();
```

jsbin : http://jsbin.com/cosetocowe/edit?html,js,output

Last comment, in the `searchColors` function, you append new elements, so as you type, you will add the refined selection at the end. Is that the behaviour you seek?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the keypress wouldn't record the value and that I wasn't returning the search.  I updated the code so that your changes are reflected.

Answer (score 1):

You could use RxJs-DOM

include script and change your search definition, thats all.

```js
var search = Rx.DOM.keyup($input)
      .pluck('target','value')
      .filter( function (text) {
        return text.length > 0;
    }).debounce(50)
    .distinctUntilChanged();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs-dom/7.0.3/rx.dom.js"></script>
```